# Incrementing Numbers With "More" Button

Tags: php

I'm writing a script that looks something like this.

```
$num = 1;
while($num <= 10) {
    echo $num;
    $num++;
}
```

The only problem is that is will only display 1-10. I want to have a "more" button that will display the next set of 10. So the output would be..

```
12345678910
```

*more*

```
1234567891011121314151617181920
```

Just really stuck on this... I'm going to use this to import Tumblr feed on my site, but it takes numbers and I don't know how to do something like this.

Comment: Are you going to reload the page?

Comment: I didn't want to @AshwinMukhija

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is pagination.

You display 10 numbers on page 1, 10 numbers on page 2 etc.

Each page starts with a *start number* and holds *offset* number of items.

This is usually implemented with a ?page=X HTTP GET parameter. Code would look something like this:

```
$offset = 10;

$page = 1;
if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page'])) {
  $page = $_GET['page'];
}
$start_number = ($page - 1) * $offset;
$end_number   = $start_number + 10;

$num = $start_number;
while ($num <= $end_number) {
  echo $num;
  $num++
  echo sprintf('<a href="/script.php?page=%s">More</a>', $page + 1)
}
```

EDIT:
I just realized you wish to load load more and more data (so not just 10 items, but 10, 20, 30 etc.). Only time this is somewhat reasonable to do is when you're using Javascript and Ajax to dynamically load new items, but even then you should be removing the old ones (so the page does not become to big). But if you're reloading the page it will take longer and longer to load it with no real benefit to the user.

Comment: That'll work! I was just hoping to get everything on one page and not keep reloading into new pages.

Comment: This is going to work! Thank you! Just one more question; it's echoing 0-10. I need it to echo 1-10 and then I need another one to echo 0-9. May sound ridicules but this is going to really help me!

Comment: To get 0-9 10-19 etc. just set $num < $end_num.
To get 1-10 etc. adding +1 to $start_number after multiplication should probably work.
But this is something you can do your self just by understanding the code and trying different variations.

Answer (score 1):

- Store `$num` in `$_SESSION` so that it is persistent across page visits.
- Or, probably better yet, make it a URL parameter, so that users visit like `your_page.php?page=30` and then use `$_GET["page"]` as `$num`.